# How would I allow other clients (Not in my LAN) to access my web socket server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have finished my websocket server, I want to be able to run it locally on my computer but I also want it to be accessible to any other client on the internet (Given they connect to my web socket)

I don't have a http server, Instead i've a webSocket.Server() object, I don't want to have any html index, It's just a javascript file

```js
const websocket = require('ws');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const wss = new websocket.Server({ port: 1337 });

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log('Client Connected')

    ws.on("message", pack => {
// Other code here
})
})
```

This is the basic layout of what I have, I'm new to all of this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find your device's IP address on your local network, and then port forward the local IP address and port through your router settings so that people outside of your network can connect to your server with your public IP.

You may also need to add firewall rules on your device so that external devices can access your server.

Comment: and would my device's IP adress be the ipv4 or default gateway? And is it possible to set the ipv4 to one value since it tends to change

Comment: @Adaptabil the gateway is your router, and you need your ipv4 to connect. To get a static IP which doesn't change you need to contact your ISP.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the help I'll come back to mark this as an answer if all goes well

Comment: @Adaptabil A static IP can be pretty hard to get (at least where I live), so you may want to look into AWS, GCP or Heroku which are free / offer a free trial to host a VPS from which you can run a websocket server

Comment: Which one of them can host a server 24/7? and also which can host a mysql server with phpadmin?

Comment: @Adaptabil All of them can host 24/7 (even heroku if you ping the server every half an hour or so). And if there's something (mysql) you can do on your terminal on your computer you can probably connect to a VPS with SSH and run it there.